# Calling private method outputs undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I receive `undefined method 'search_type'` for the code below. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here? Probably something with calling private functions, but I can't find what the problem is.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :rank, :title, :url, :user_id

  def self.search(params)
    t, o = search_type(params[:type]),search_order(params[:order])
    scope = self

    scope = scope.where(t) if t
    scope.order(o).page(params[:page]).per_page(20)
  end

  private

  def search_order(order)
    return 'comments_count DESC' if order == '1'
    return 'points DESC' if order == '2'

    'rank DESC'
  end

  def search_type(type)
    return nil unless type.present?

    "entry_type = #{type}"
  end
end
```

In the controller, I have only `@entries = Entry.search(params)`.

Comment: I mistyped controller line, fixed already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not to do with the privateness of your methods, but the fact that `search` is a class method, so when you call `search_order` from within it, it is looking for a class method called `search_order` but you've defined `search_order` as in instance method.

Make your 2 helper methods class methods and you should be ok. if you want them to be private class methods, then

```
class << self
  def search(...)
  end
  private
  def search_type(...)
  end
  def search_order(...)
  end
end
```

If you are wondering why `@entries.search(...)` works it's because I assume that @entries is something like `Entry.where(...)` ie, a scope and you can call class methods on scopes.

Comment: Thanks, it works, just have to understand why :). So any method I call from class method has to be class method as well?

Comment: if you don't supply an explicit receiver, yes: `search_order` is the same as `self.search_order` and self is the class rather than an instance of the class

Comment: thanks ! it fixed my issue. I didn't know this subtle rule.

Answer (score 0):

`search` is defined as a class method, so you should call `Entry.search(params)` instead of `@entries.search(params)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is an a class method, you cant use it form instances of your class